# Navigate to a view thats within a navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a Tab Bar Controller which contains 4 views. 3 views are very basic. Just a tableview with data (Call one of these views SimpleTableView). The 4th view points to a Navigation Controller with two buttons on its view (Lets call this view MainNavView). Both buttons point to different views (Lets call them ViewA and ViewB) and a user can go back to the view with two buttons (MainNavView) when pressing the back button on the Navigationbar. Works great.

Now here is my problem. I want the didSelectRowAtIndexPath from SimpleTableView to show ViewA from the Navigation Controller. And when a user lands on that page he can press the back button on the navigationbar and the MainNavView appears.

Navigating from MainNavView to ViewA is done with a (push) segue:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:nil];
}
```

The MainStoryBoard contains a segue from a tableviewcell inside MainNavView to ViewA called "segueIdentifier".

I tried making another segue from a tableviewcell inside SimpleTableView to ViewA and executing this code again:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:nil];
}
```

but then I get this error

```
NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController
```

Now this error is easily fixed when I embed SimpleTableView inside a Navigation Controller but thats not what I want because the back button returns the user to SimpleTableView and not MainNavView.

I hope everything is clear and someone can help me with this navigation problem. Is this maybe possible with a modal segue instead of push?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use push segue from a controller that isn't an`UINavigationController`, you should use the **modal** segue pointing directly to `ViewA`. I just tried it, it works flawlessly !

From the user's point of view, push segues are explicit transitions from/to the same view hierarchy... I think that using a push segue from another tab could disorient the user...

Comment: I've tried it with a modal and it works but then ViewA wont show a navigation bar with a back button to "MainNavView".